# CSS Gradience Isn't Working

Tags: html, background, gradient, css

I'm coding this webpage for a project and I can't get the gradient background to show up. I'm making sure that my code is compatible for multiple browsers, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

  <title>About Leo Alfred: 12/14/2013</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      background: linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      color: #E9EEF2;
      min-height:100%;
      margin:0;
    }


    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #me {
      height: 600px;
      width: 500px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      margin-left: auto;
    margih3 {ght: text-align: center;diu}: 12px;
      }

    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Leo Alfred<h1>
  <img id = "me" src="assets/Leo_Pic.jpeg" title = "A Picture of Leo Alfred" alt="Leo Alfred"</div>
  <h2>Leo Alfred</h2>
  <h3>School and BDPA</h3>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for helping me!

All things posted have helped with the gradience, but only two thirds of the way down the page. After that it is just a blue rectangle.

Please go to http://bdpastudents.com/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_1/HTMLLab1.html to see what I'm talking about when I say blue rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property isn't correct. It should just be `background:linear-gradient(etc, etc)` as opposed to `background-color`.

If you take your code as is and literally just delete the word color, it works fine.

***Edit:*** If you wanted it to be gradient blocks, then I'm sorry to say that I don't know how to help. But if you'd prefer one gradient top to bottom like this: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/designedtorule/vgzZW/embedded/result/), then all you have to do is change the css selector from body to html.

Hope that works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

  <title>About Leo Alfred: 12/14/2013</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    html
    {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      background: linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
      color: #E9EEF2;
      min-height:100%;
      margin:0;
    }


    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #me {
      height: 600px;
      width: 500px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      margin-left: auto;
    margin {ght: text-align: center;diu}: 12px;
      }

    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Leo Alfred<h1>
  <img id = "me" src="assets/Leo_Pic.jpeg" title = "A Picture of Leo Alfred" alt="Leo Alfred"</div>
  <h2></div>Leo Alfred</h2>
  <h3>School and BDPA</h3>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did remove the -color. That gets the gradience to appear, but the gradience only goes 2 thirds of the way down the page and below that is just a blue color.

Comment: Is this what's happening? [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/designedtorule/vgzZW/embedded/result/)

Comment: Don't you see the blue rectangle at the bottom of the screen? That's my only problem.

Comment: ohhhhhh... I actually didn't notice that at all. I don't understand why it's in blocks like that in the first place...shouldn't it be one overall gradient from top to bottom?

Comment: That's what I don't understand either. The gradience isn't the real problem it's that block at the bottom.

Comment: I GOT IT! Change your selector to html (I edited it in the block of code in my answer) and it works like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/designedtorule/vgzZW/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0):

`linear-gradient` is a type of `background-image`, not a `background-color`.

Comment: That gets the gradience to appear, but the gradience only goes 2 thirds of the way down the page and below that is just a blue color. Also in the above code I had this random </div> tag and I got rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct format for a gradient. Also, gradients are images, not colours.

```
background-image:linear-gradient(direction, colour, colour, ...)
```

So in your case:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4B647A, #081C2E);
```

Comment: That gets the gradience to appear, but the gradience only goes 2 thirds of the way down the page and below that is just a blue color.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your css from:

```
background-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
background-color: -o-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
background-color: linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
```

To:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
background: linear-gradient(#4B647A, #081C2E);
```

A link worth mentioning is the MDN documentation on CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: That gets the gradience to appear, but the gradience only goes 2 thirds of the way down the page and below that is just a blue color.